# How to automatically show alert iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I have a Device Firmware Update view where I update the physical devices' firmware.
**My goal is** to show the alert when the DFU state is `.completed`. That means I want to bind the alert popup to the state, not to the action.
Here is what I have so far:

```
func showDFUCompletedAlert() {
     let dfuAlert = UIAlertController(title: "The device firmware is updated successfully.", message: "You will be redirected back to the Devices list. To get back to your device just tap on it without refreshing Devices list.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
     dfuAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {_ in
            self.dfuUpdate = nil
        }))
        
     self.present(dfuAlert, animated: true)
    }
```

So, the question is: how do I show the alert right after the device firmware update is completed without tapping on the buttons etc?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Adding the code of the DFU States:

```
func dfuStateDidChange(to state: DFUState) {
     print(state.description())
     case .connecting:
            self.updateView?.selectButton.isHidden = true
     case .starting:
            self.updateView?.selectButton.isHidden = true
     case .aborted:
            self.updateView?.selectButton.isHidden = false
            self.updateView?._fileURL = nil
            self.updateView?.fileNameLabel.text = "Select file"
     case .completed:
     supportDelegate?.showDFUCompletedAlert()
}
```

**UPDATE [2]:** Breakpoint report:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
    0x18f63c0ec <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x1f
    0x18f63c0f0 <+4>: svc    #0x80
->  0x18f63c0f4 <+8>: ret
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using to update the firmware.

Comment: Hello @EmilioPelaez and thank you so much for the comment and your time! The code I am using for updating the firmware is basically a bunch of functions connected and located in different places, so this is not gonna be pretty if I add everything related to it. Anyway, is this crucial to add? If so, I'll try my best. However, I've added the function where I am calling this alert popup.

Comment: you are calling it ... but its not showing ?

Comment: Hi @jawadAli ! Yes, exactly. As you see in the presented above code, I am using the  ```case .completed```, but it doesn't work. Whereas other cases work fine.

Comment: Any console warnings or errors?  Did you check that `supportDelegate` isn't nil?

Comment: what are the other states that are executing ?

Comment: Are you sure to set the other controller to delegate of the one which owns `dfuStateDidChange` method? Simply add breakpoint into the `showDFUCompletedAlert` method to check if the code reach it or not. If not, your problem is the delegates

Comment: add breakpoint in cases to see which is firing .... first question is if its coming in completed case or not?

Comment: Add breakpoint on "self.present(dfuAlert, animated: true)" and print the "self" for that screen then check, is it nil, or have some values?

Comment: Hello @vpoltave ! I have just tested once again - no errors or warnings.

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra please, see the Update [2] - I added the report.

Comment: @jawadAli , the others states that are executing are updated in the original code. Please, look at them.

Comment: @Dris , you're right. I have found the problem thanks to your comment! Now I'll just try a different solution.

Comment: @Lilya, what is output of this line "print(state.description())"  under the "dfuStateDidChange"  method? and what's the output of "po supportDelegate" in the console panel?

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra the output is: ```Connecting
Starting
Uploading
Disconnecting
Completed```

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra , as @Dris mentioned above, the problem is in exactly the delegate. I have the extension where I am using ```DFUServiceDelegate, DFUProgressDelegate```, and what I did wrong was calling the delegate in the class, not the extension. However, my extension can't conform to ```supportDelegate```.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much! I found the problem thanks to your help!

Comment: Common mistake, I was happy to help you :)

Comment: @Dris thanks once again for helping out with your advice on delegates. Could you be so kind to post this answer so that I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out in comments, you forget to set the delegates for your controller, and the `showDFUCompletedAlert()` method didn't run.